# Calculating plant proportion Landsat

Tags: remote-sensing, heat-map, ndvi, landsat-8

I have this paper. In equation 2 they are calculating surface emissivity.
I want to ask what is  v plant proportion?

https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=5760fe20b0366df3a5237081&assetKey=AS%3A373137431646209%401465974304318

```
 = **  + [ −]  +
  is the vegetation proportion in a pixel
```

Was it calculated from NDVI?

Comment: I think it could be the same as [Fractional Vegetation Cover](http://www.mdpi.com/1424-8220/9/2/768), take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the article:

> Land surface emissivity was calculated
>   using the NDVI threshold method [38] suggested by Beck et
>   al. [42]. The assumption is that bare has a NDVI < 0.2 [42].
>   The land surface is considered to be completely covered by
>   vegetation if NDVI > 0.5 [42]. When the NDVI values are
>   between 0.1 and 0.5 (0.1 ≤ NDVI ≤ 0.5), the land surface is
>   considered to be covered by vegetation and bare soil mixing.

As such, P_v is 0 at NDVI < 0.2, 1 at >0.5 and scaled inbetween (on a related note, the values used in this article were chosen for their location. Your location may require different values).

Calculating such a 'fractional vegetation cover' map is done using a linear regression and a raster calculator.